# Why I don't have rw access to /run which is mounted as tmpfs in docker?

Tags: docker, tmpfs

```
❯ docker run -d -it --name debian --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/run,tmpfs-mode=1777 --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/tmp,tmpfs-mode=1777 debian bash


❯ docker exec -it debian ls -lrtd /run /tmp
  drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 40 Jul 27 14:06 /tmp
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 Jul 27 14:06 /run
```

Here, why is `tmpfs-mode=1777` is not getting applied to the /run alone?
It works perfectly fine for other directories.
Any specific reason here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that since `/run` already exists, the permissions of that directory are being applied to the `tmpfs` mount. The same thing is happening with `/tmp`, but since the permissions on the underlying `/tmp` directory already match what you want you don't notice it.

You can verify this by creating `tmpfs` mounts on other directories (e.g., `/root`). You'll see that they adopt the permissions of the mountpoint.

If you really need the permissions on `/run` to be different, you could build a new image with your desired permissions on `/run` (or just run `chmod` once the container is running).